# Software for granular real-time wifi strength monitoring

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitor, wifi

I have a Windows desktop machine with a nice wifi card in it, and I've just moved to a new temporary location. The router here is in the basement for some reason, so I've been having some connectivity issues (and it's not my building so I can't go moving things around; for the same reason I can't run ethernet to the machine).

My wifi card is 802.11ac, so the external portion has three antennas on it. I want to position these antennas such that I get the strongest signal possible from where my desktop is.

Is there any software that can give me a real-time readout of wifi signal strength, so I can adjust my antenna setup and watch to see how that changes things? It needs to be something more granular then the wifi bars that Windows shows everyone.

Software would preferably be free, but if it's priced under $25 I would be willing to check it out. I would also be interested in similar software for Android or Linux, but more just out of curiosity. The Windows software would be the practical one for me.